# What will be vo/i for given circuit?

Tags: bjt, feedback, negative-feedback

[image]

[image]

Solve using both approaches first using small signal analysis and then using feedback analysis.

Comment: the correct answer is 33x10^3

Comment: As shown without DC bias, the source impedance =0 what input current is there for a small signal. Base bias is missing or must be coupled with a cap to allow self bias. FIx your question again pls.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 Is it fine now

Comment: @G36 then why the answer coming out by feedback analysis is different